# Multi selection input only submits the last selection

Tags: php, forms

I have a simple form, inside it there is check-boxes and multi selection inputs.

The problem I am having is:

1. The multi selection input only submits the last selection!
2. The checkboxes only works if I set a value="" but shouldn't work without it?

Here is the form:

```
<fieldset>
    <p>Multi selection</p>
    <select name="dropdown2[]" class="select multi-select " data-placeholder="Choose an option" multiple="multiple">
        <optgroup label="Section">
            <option>Drop Down Option A</option>
            <option>Drop Down Option B</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Section">
            <option>Drop Down Option A</option>
            <option>Drop Down Option B</option>
        </optgroup>
    </select>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <p>Optional checkboxs</p>
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input name="11" type="checkbox"><span><i></i></span>
        <p>CheckA</p>
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input name="11" type="checkbox"><span><i></i></span>
        <p>CheckB</p>
    </label>
</fieldset>
```

Here is the PHP:

```
<?php
// Only start sessions if they haven't been already to prevent errors
if (empty($_SESSION)){session_start();}

// If 'data' var was received via POST from form-validation.js
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    // There's not really a need for this line with modern browsers
    ob_start();

    // Open the div around the message
    $message = "<div style=\"styling stuff\">";

    // Loop through every single post value
    foreach ($_REQUEST as $key => $value) {
        // If it's not empty
        if (!empty($value)) {
            // Change the name attributes to look a bit more human-readable
            $thisKey = str_replace("-", " ", str_replace("_", "|", $key));

            // Populate the message var
            $message .= "<strong>" . $thisKey . ":</strong> " . $value . "<br />";
        }
    }
    // Close the div around the message
    $message .= '</div>';

    // Mail variables
    $to = 'email@email.com';
    $subject = 'New Message';
    $headers = "From: email@email.com\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: email@email.com\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

    // Attempt to send
    $sendMail = @mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

    // If it fails...
    if (!$sendMail) {
        // Terminate processing with error
        die("There was a problem sending the email");
    } else {
        // Terminate processing with success msg
        die("Email was sent!");
    }

    // As above, no real need for this line with modern browsers
    ob_flush();

    // Terminate
    die();
}
?>
```

Live preview: http://loaistudio.com/contact

Comment: Have you tried to `var_dump($_REQUEST);` ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send multiple values via checkboxes, then they should be used in this way

```
<input name="11[]" type="checkbox"> 
<input name="11[]" type="checkbox">
```

instead of

```
<input name="11" type="checkbox">
```

Comment: Will try that, however, it will cause the same problem i am having with the selection now... it will only show the last selction

Comment: It will allow you to send multiple values. Just check on the back-end via `var_dump($_POST['11'])`.

Comment: when I add the [] to the checkboxes it shows an error: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input:checkbox[name=11[]]:last

Comment: You seem to have included additional javascript. Please edit your question appropriately. Moreover, try creating a simple form with multiple checkboxes using array-styled names. You'd see that it works.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to submit multi check box then 
use like this

```
<input name="11[]" type="checkbox" value="someval"> 
<input name="11[]" type="checkbox" value="someval"  >
```

this will post checkbox elements as array

to retrieve

```
$chk = $_POST['11']; // this will be array
```

iterate through this array you will get all checked elements of name 11

still you need to provide some values to check box to work this